# Poor performance for UIPanGestureRecognizer in iOS 8

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios8

I have a view with 3 table views side by side.  The user can pan between the table views (just showing one on the screen at a time.)

I'm using the `UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged` to update a constraint constant that more or less follows the x distance travelled by the user's guesture.

The poor performance is noticeable even on the simulator and a 5s.

The offending code is here:

```
switch (gestureRecognizer.state) {
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan:
            [self.tableContainer.layer removeAllAnimations];
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged:
        // the below is where the UI performance suffers
        {
              CGFloat leftEdgeConstant = [self calculateConstantSomehow];
            self.leftEdgeConstraint.constant = leftEdgeConstant;
        }
            break;
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded:
        case UIGestureRecognizerStateCancelled:
        // continue...
```

In iOS7 it was buttery smooth.

Animating between the table views via `UIView` class methods is smooth.

Anyone have any ideas?  Can we not change constraint constants like this anymore?